# Adding Title field to each individual file by Jquery File Upload?

Tags: jquery, file, upload, blueimp

Using Jquery File Upload by Blueimp I'd like to add a title field for each file uploaded. So that once a file was uploaded a text box for title was added below each file.
I do not understand the documentation suppported by the Blueimp API.

https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/How-to-submit-additional-form-data

I do not know where to put these code:

```
<script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
    <tr class="template-upload fade">
        <!-- ... -->
        <td class="title"><label>Title: <input name="title[]" required></label></td>
        <!-- ... -->
    </tr>
{% } %}
</script>
```

---

```
$('#fileupload').bind('fileuploadsubmit', function (e, data) {
    var inputs = data.context.find(':input');
    if (inputs.filter(function () {
            return !this.value && $(this).prop('required');
        }).first().focus().length) {
        data.context.find('button').prop('disabled', false);
        return false;
    }
    data.formData = inputs.serializeArray();
});
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it.
U can find the configuration info in the script(id:template-upload).
Each td is for the auto generating item. So you can put the "Title: " in these.

The second JS part I posted is for submitting the form data. You can put these in  the html body.